# How to avoid Pirc in favor of KID

Tags: kings-indian, pirc-defense

I like to play the King's Indian Defense (KID) and I know little to nothing about the Pirc. So, on 1.d4 I always go for 1. ... Nf6 but I don't know what to do to avoid 2.Nc3 g6 3.e4 d6 ending up in a Pirc. Do I have to change a move order somehow or there's simply no other way than studying how to tackle this Pirc position with black?

Comment: 2...Nxe4 wins a pawn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you cannot force white to play c4 and end up in a KID.

However, if you want to avoid the Pirc, you have several options after 1. d4 Nf6 2. Nc3.

- 2. ... d5 is the most popular and you usually end up in easy to play positions. E.g. you can fianchetto your bishop to g7, attack the center with c5, etc.. You need to be prepared for the Hübsch/Blackmar-Diemer Gambit after 3. e4, but that is nothing to be afraid of.
- 2. ... c5 to attack the center immediately
- 2. ... e6 which can transpose into the French defense

Answer (score 4):

after 1.d4,Nf6 2.Nc3 one can use 2...d5. Since White cannot easily play c4, he cannot apply pressure on the d pawn (as in queen's gambit for example). As a result, Black has a very easy opening.